# How to convert from TimeSpan to DateTime and back using a TypeConverter?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have an entity that has a `TimeSpan` property which represents the time of day. I also have a custom `TimePicker` usercontrol which has a default `Value` property of type `DateTime?`. The usercontrol works fine when using entities with `DateTime` properties.

I'm also using `BindingSource` to bind the entity to the form controls.

However, when using `TimeSpan`, the value is obviously not set. is it possible to use a `TypeConverter` to automatically convert from TImeSpan to DateTime?

Comment: That depends how you want it to convert, since timespan is not the same as a date. It is a duration. For example, you could do DateTime.Now + timespan

Comment: Can you change your entity? TimeSpan is not meant for storing a point in time, it's a length of time.

Comment: You can add a `DateTime` representing a date and a Timespan to get back a full date+time value. *Do* you have a Date field though?

Comment: @SteveJ I'm using TimeSpan because the property is mapped to a `time(7)` column in SQL Server

Comment: @SteveJ on the contrary, `TimeSpan` is the correct type to map time of day, until the `System.Time` type arrives. `TimeSpan` is what the `time` type of SQL Server maps to.

Comment: I stand corrected. I guess if the TimePicker needs a DateTime, then use `DateTime.Today + theTimeSpan`. DateTime.Today returns midnight last night.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono if the controlis a *TimePicker* why does it require a *DateTime* property? Either modify it to accept the *logical* type, TimeSpan, or modify it to accept both types, possibly by using two different properties

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono btw data should be displayed by using data binding to properties, not setting the `.Value` properties of controls directly. The control should suppor databinding and inspect the type of the value being set